# What is the difference between properties "Caption", "DNSHostName" and "Name" in "wmic computersystem get /all"

Tags: cmd, wmic

So

I'm trying to do a simple thing: rename the computer name using CMD (and/or batch).

In CMD, when I type `wmic computersystem get /all` amongst other entries, I get `Caption`, `DNSHostName` and `Name` variables, all of those having the exact same value: `TEST-PC`.

What is the difference between those entries? **Which one should I change to change the actual PC name**?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be that `caption` is equivalent to 'Computer description' on Windows. When setting a computer name on Windows it'll set `name` and  `DNSHostname` to the same thing, however they can be different. I'd suggest seeing all three, with `caption` being something a bit more readable, `name` and `DNSHostname` should probably remain in sync for ease but make them something url-friendly

Comment: When outputing from CMD I get the following: 

`Caption=TEST-PC`
`DNSHostName=TEST-PC`
`Name=TEST-PC`

Furthermore, when I go to "Control Panel\System and Security\System" (WinKey+Pause) I get the following: 
`Computer name: TEST-PC` 
`Full computer name: TEST-PC` 
 `Computer description: ` (empty) << it's just blank, it's not actually written "empty" 

So my assumption is that "Caption" (from CMD) is NOT the equivalent to "Computer description" from the System panel in Windows. 

So my question still remains: Which one should I change to change the actual PC name? 

Thanks :)